# How to sort by column Date that is greater than DATE(NOW())?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have date_end column that I need to sort where it's only important to top rows with date greater than today.

So give date greater than today = "1", smaller = "0" and sort that.

So with below data table:

```
+----+------------+ 
| id | date_end   |  
+----+------------+ 
| 1  | 31-01-2018 |  
+----+------------+ 
| 2  | 01-05-2019 |  
+----+------------+ 
| 3  | 31-05-2018 |  
+----+------------+ 
| 4  | 31-07-2019 |  
+----+------------+ 
| 5  | 31-04-2020 |  
+----+------------+ 
| 6  | 31-08-2019 |  
+----+------------+
```

I need to virtually add "actual" column and sort by it:

```
+----+------------+--------+
| id | date_end   | actual |
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | 31-01-2018 | 0      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 2  | 01-05-2019 | 0      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 3  | 31-05-2018 | 0      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 4  | 31-07-2019 | 1      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 5  | 31-04-2020 | 1      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 6  | 31-08-2019 | 1      |
+----+------------+--------+
```

Something like:
ORDER BY CASE WHEN `date_end` > DATE(NOW()) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then do exactly as you suggested:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN date_end > curdate() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can take advantage of the fact that boolean expressions can be used directly.  So:

```
order by (date_end > curdate()) desc
```

The "true" > "false", so `desc` puts the true values first.